# Timer jumping several seconds ahead when restarting after pause in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have some logic to handle a timer in my react-native app. Right now I'm observing some strange behavior. When I first start the timer it ticks on as expected. When I click `stop` it shows the last value. Then when I click start again it should pick up the last value and continue to increment on. However, what's happening is on re-start the value is jumping ahead by several seconds, and incrementing from there, and I'm not sure why.

There are four main components: `_startTimer()`, `_stopTimer()`, `calculateDuration()`, and `continueTimer()`.

The problem seems to happen when `_continueTimer()` gets run, and specifically when `_calculateDuration()` is called from within that function.

```
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.timer = null;
     this.state = {
       duration: props?.duration || '00:00:00',
       startTime: props?.started ? moment(props.started).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss') : null,
       stopTime: props?.stopped ? moment(props.stopped).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss') : null,
     };
   }
   
   async _startTimer() {
     if (this.timer) clearInterval(this.timer);
     
     let stateUpdate = {
       stopTime: null,
     };
     
     if (!this.state.startTime) {
       const newStartTime = moment(Date.serverTime() || Date.now());
       stateUpdate.startTime = newStartTime.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
     }
     
     this.setState(stateUpdate, () => {
       this.timer = setInterval(async () => {
         const newDuration = this._calculateDuration();
         this.setState({
           duration: newDuration,
         });
       }, 1000);
       if (this.props.onChange) this.props.onChange(this.state);
     });
   };
   
   _stopTimer() {
     return new Promise((resolve) => {
       if (this.timer) clearInterval(this.timer);
       
       const newStopTime = moment(Date.serverTime());
       this.setState({
         stopTime: newStopTime.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'),
       }, async () => {
         if (this.props.onChange) await this.props.onChange(this.state);
       });
     });
   };

   _calculateDuration() {
        const startTime = moment(this.state.startTime).valueOf();
        
        const stopTime = this.state.stopTime ? moment(this.state.stopTime).valueOf() : moment().valueOf();

        const duration = moment.duration(stopTime - startTime).asMilliseconds();
        const durationFormatted = moment.utc(duration).format('HH:mm:ss');
        return durationFormatted;
    };
     
    async _continueTimer() {
        if (this.timer) clearInterval(this.timer);
        
        this.setState({
            stopTime: null,
        }, () => {
            this.timer = setInterval(async () => {
                const newDuration = this._calculateDuration();
                this.setState({
                    duration: newDuration,
                });
            }, 1000);
            
            if (this.props.onChange) this.props.onChange(this.state);
        });
    };
```

Comment: did this work? If so can you mark as answered, I'm interested

Answer (score 1):

@muirik I just tried following the chain of calls and what I think is happening is after stopping, then restarting, `_startTimer()` is being called instead of `_continueTimer()`. Either that, or it's that you don't reset the value of `state.Starttime` in the `_continueTimer()` method. Either way, the reason is the same:

**Example below**

If You go from a brand new timer:

`Start button is hit,  start time is 12:00:00 (For sake of argument)`

Wait 1 second

`interval happens, duration is calculated as 12:00:01 - 12:00:00 = 0:0:01`

Press stop

`StopTimer happens,stop time is 12:00:01 , duration is 0:0:01`

Wait 5 seconds

Press Start Button again (Assume start is called instead of continue)

`start sets state.stopTime to null, then skips the following:`

```
if (!this.state.startTime) {
   const newStartTime = moment(Date.serverTime() || Date.now());
   stateUpdate.startTime = newStartTime.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
 }
```

`start time is still 12:00:01`

1 second passes - time is 12:00:07

`Time interval gets called, difference is calculated. start time is 12:00:01, current time is 12:00:07 , duration goes from 0:0:01 to 0:0:07`

My recommendation would be to look into where you make a call to these methods and set the start time state to the current moment on 'continueTime'